# Remote Desktop Gateway Server is Temporarily Unavailable. AWS remote connection

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, windows-10, remote-desktop-gateway

I'm trying to connect using Windows 10 remote desktop connection (default app). Now I was given an RDP credential now upon trying to connect and prompted with User and Password which I inputted

```
 Username: Administrator
 Password: <The password given to me>
 Server Name: ec2-....compute.amazonaws.com
```

But I got this error message. Not sure how to go about this. Is there anything I need to do in the AWS Console to make thi work? or do I need to modify something in the local machine I'm using?

Note: remote access to computer is enabled in my LOCAL MACHINE. I'm not sure in the AWS side since I don't have access to it. But the administrator said that the port is already enabled for port number 3389. So I have no idea on what to do now.

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you telnet on the RDP port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue. It seems that the provided RDP Connection is defective and I had to create/generate my own user with a new password. And using the IP address of my AWS and the new username/password I was able to create in the RDP